# Does ruby have an identity function, i.e. x.fn == x, for all x?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes when I'm passing a method name as an argument, I find myself wishing for an identity function such that `any_obj.send(:identity) == any_obj`, so instead of this:

```
(transform.nil?) ? my_obj : my_obj.send(transform)
```

I could just write

```
my_obj.send(transform || :identity)
```

(This is a bit of a contrived example -- an identity function could do more than save a few keystrokes in more complicated examples.)

It would be easy enough to open up the definition of Object and add it, but is there something already there that I've overlooked?  Does anyone else want this as well?

P.S.: I know my example should really be stated `any_obj.send(:identity).equal?(any_obj)`, but sometimes pedantry obscures the question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes. You're looking for [`Object#itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-itself), which is available in Ruby 2.2+.

From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-itself):

> ## itself → an_object
>
> Returns obj.
>
> ```
> string = 'my string' #=> "my string"
> string.itself.object_id == string.object_id #=> true
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932711/is-there-a-short-way-to-write-x-x). It seems that now, Ruby [is going to have `#itself` method](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373).

Comment: It's reassuring to know I'm asking a sensible question.  Thanks.

Comment: Great news! The example given at the link illustrates nicely why it's needed (a definite improvement over, say, `group_by(&:floor)` for integers or `group_by(&:dup)` for mutables.

Answer (score 2):

There is not any for now, but Matz has expressed an opinion favoring such method to be implemented: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373. It is likely to be implemented in future versions of Ruby.

Comment: It _has been_ implemented just now.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Do you mean 19 days ago?

Comment: Yep. 19 days ago, in August 2014.