# Is there an identity function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I'm currently writing a Ruby class that provides a menu of base lambdas that can be mixed-and-matched to create a new set of lambdas. (it's an evolutionary algorithm that requires a lot of customizing of the fitness function depending on the dataset)

The configuration fire where this happens it full of stuff like this

`function_from_modifier.(base_function, either.(modifier_from.(case),->(x){x}) )`

The identity function `->(x){x}` pops up several times in the configuration file, and it looks ugly, so I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this. Is something like Elixir's `&(&1)` possible in Ruby?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ruby have an identity function, i.e. x.fn == x, for all x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558351/does-ruby-have-an-identity-function-i-e-x-fn-x-for-all-x)

Comment: @picklerick the answer you’ve linked obviously does not answer this question because `Object#itself` in many ways differs from [tag:elixir]’s `& &1`, as I pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** summary: there is no identity function in the Ruby core or standard libraries. In fact, there are no functions (in the sense of pre-defined `Proc` instances) *at all* anywhere in the core or standard libraries.

First-class functions in Ruby are kind-of second-class (if that makes sense).

When Yukihiro "matz" Matsumoto first designed Ruby, he surveyed the standard libraries of other languages for uses of first-class and higher-order functions, and he found that the vast majority of uses were:

- a single function argument
- that is not stored, passed, or returned
- that is only immediately invoked one or more times

A significant portion of higher-order functions where this is *not* true are control structures (e.g. `if` which takes a condition and two consequences), which however he wanted to model as built-in language constructs, not library functions.

Therefore, he decided to optimize Ruby for the common case that he identified, and created *blocks*.

*Blocks* are *not* first-class functions:

- they aren't objects
- you can't send messages to them
- they can't be stored in variables
- they can't be returned
- they can't be freely passed as arguments, you can only pass at most one and only at a special place in the argument list

As a result, *real* (in the sense that they are actual objects) first-class functions (`Proc`s) are in some sense second-class language features compared to blocks:

- they are more expensive in memory
- calling them is slower
- they are more syntactically cumbersome to create

So, in essence, it is not surprising that you are running into limitations when trying to use Ruby the way you do: that's not what Ruby was designed for.

In the past, I used to carry around a helper library with constants such like this:

```rb
class Proc
  Id = -> x { x }
end
```

But I stopped doing that. If I want to use Ruby, I use Ruby as an OO language, if I want to do fancy FP, I use Haskell or Scala or Clojure or Racket or …

Answer (score 3):

There is no anonymous functions capture in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), because in OOP there are objects having methods defined on them, not functions.

The most similar call would be [`Object#itself`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-itself), and while one might do `method(:itself)` instead of `->(x) { x }`, it would not be exactly same for many reasons.

Why would not you just assign the anonymous function to the variable and use it instead, like `λ = ->(x) { x }` and then use `λ` everywhere?

*Sidenote:* using a bare function instead of the block in call to `either` looks like a bad design to me. Blocks are faster, and everywhere in the core lib [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) uses blocks in such a case.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I use a bare function instead of a block is that this doesn't happen in the main program, it happens in a configuration file, where a  user with little programming knowledge can create a fitness function by combining the base functions in different ways. Maybe there is a better way of doing this? Would a DSL be appropriate here?

Comment: Definitely it’s a perfect use case for DSL. You have a _domain_ and you need a _specific language_ for it :)

Comment: "_Sidenote:_ using a bare function instead of the block in call to `either` looks like a bad design to me. Blocks are faster, and everywhere in the core lib [tag:ruby] uses blocks in such a case." – `either` takes *two* functions as an argument. You can only pass *one* block. Therefore, you *have* to pass a function. You *could* make it one function and one block, but that would be strangely asymmetrical.