# Group by identity in Ruby

Tags: ruby, grouping, identity

How does Ruby's [`group_by()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method group an array by the identity (or rather `self`) of its elements?

```
a = 'abccac'.chars
# => ["a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "c"]

a.group_by(&:???)
# should produce...
# { "a" => ["a", "a"],
#   "b" => ["b"],
#   "c" => ["c", "c", "c"] }
```

Comment: Found a old but similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16932711/846163

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In a newer Ruby (2.2+?),

```
a.group_by(&:itself)
```

In an older one, you still need to do `a.group_by { |x| x }`

Comment: Thanks, here is the documentation link to [Object#itself()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) in Ruby 2.2. BTW I used `&:to_s` to provide the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this will help:

```
a = 'abccac'.chars
a.group_by(&:to_s)
#=> {"a"=>["a", "a"], "b"=>["b"], "c"=>["c", "c", "c"]}
```

Alternatively, below will also work:

```
a = 'abccac'.chars
a.group_by(&:dup)
#=> {"a"=>["a", "a"], "b"=>["b"], "c"=>["c", "c", "c"]}
```